# JOIN CTE's Grouped by Month/Year

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have multiple CTEs which result in the following common table structure:

```
Year | Month | Total_Purchases_Product_Line_X
```

These represent purchases grouped by month & year across several product lines.

Ex.)

```
SELECT * FROM cte_line_x    

Year | Month | Total_Purchases_Product_Line_X
2018    01      256
2018    02      192

SELECT * FROM cte_line_y    

Year | Month | Total_Purchases_Product_Line_Y
2018    01      76
2018    02      59
```

I'd like to create something like the following

```
Year | Month | Total_Purchases_Line_X | Total_Purchases_Line_Y | Total_Purchases_Line_Z
2018    01     256                       76
2018    02     192                       59
```

Where the total purchases of each product line is joined. However, I'm running into issues grouping the dates from each CTE after I have joined them together.
Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    cte_product_x.Month, 
    cte_product_x.Year, 
    cte_product_x.total as Total_X, 
    cte_product_y.total as Total_Y, 
    cte_product_z.total as Total_Z
FROM 
     cte_product_x
LEFT JOIN
     cte_product_y ON
     cte_product_y.year = cte_product_x.year
     AND
     cte_product_y.month = cte_product_x.month
LEFT JOIN
     cte_product_z ON
     cte_product_z.year = cte_product_x.year
     AND
     cte_product_z.month = cte_product_x.month
 GROUP BY 
    cte_product_x.Month, 
    cte_product_x.Year
  ORDER BY 
    cte_product_x.Month, 
    cte_product_x.Year
```

I tried changing my SELECT to:

```
SELECT 
    cte_product_x.Month, 
    cte_product_x.Year, 
    MAX(cte_product_x.total as Total_X), 
    MAX(cte_product_y as Total_Y), 
    MAX(cte_product_z as Total_Z)
```

However, it only worked for "Total_X". The counts for the other columns were the max value found for a grouped total for all months. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
SELECT x.Month, x.Year, x.total as Total_X, 
       y.total as Total_Y, z.total as Total_Z
FROM cte_product_x x JOIN
     cte_product_y y
     ON y.year = x.year AND y.month = x.month JOIN
     cte_product_z z
     ON z.year = x.year AND z.month = x.month
ORDER BY x.Month, x.Year;
```

At least it works for your sample data.

Comment: Yeah it does. I just checked my actual SQL and the reason I thought this wasn't working is because I was joining the same CTE into itself :( oh boy. It's 5' o clock -  right? lol Ty